# How do I optimize this R code currently using rbind()?

Tags: r, optimization

This is an excerpt from my code (cut for brevity):

```
sample.faktisktdata <- function(n) {
    Ntriangeldata <- Ndata[sample(nrow(Ndata), n, replace=TRUE),]
    faktiskt.data <- data.frame()

    for (i in 1:n) {
        faktiskt.data <- rbind(faktiskt.data,
                               faktisktdata[faktisktdata$NR %in% Ntriangeldata$NR[i],])
    }

    # ...
}
```

This function, `sample.faktisktdata`, runs in about 5 seconds on my machine when called with n=2000. I believe the culprit is the for-loop with a call to `rbind`. I know that using `rbind` in a for-loop is notoriously slow, and I've spent hours trying to figure out how to rewrite this in a more optimized way, but I'm stuck.

One way I tried was to create a pre-allocated data.frame with 20,000 rows, and then populating it row-by-row. This turned out to be slower (about 3x slower) for some reason. That looked like this:

```
sample.faktisktdata <- function(n) {
    Ntriangeldata <- Ndata[sample(nrow(Ndata), n, replace=TRUE), ]

    faktiskt.data <- data.frame(matrix(ncol=13, nrow=20000))
    colnames(faktiskt.data) <- colnames(faktisktdata)
    count <- 0

    for (i in 1:n) {
        dataToInsert <- faktisktdata[faktisktdata$NR %in% Ntriangeldata$NR[i],]

        if (nrow(dataToInsert) > 0) {
            for (j in 1:nrow(dataToInsert)) {
                faktiskt.data[count,] <- dataToInsert[j,]
                count <- count + 1
            }
        }
    }

    // ...
}
```

Some sample rows from Ndata (containing a total of 4738 rows, and I apologize for the Swedish column names):

```
> Ndata[1:5,]
          NR skadedatum rapportdatum  slutdatum betaldatum utbetalning  totalut reserv regress skadekostnad skadeår rapportår
2  000002-16 2013-12-03   2016-01-15 2016-11-02 2016-06-20    4126.304 47147.64      0       0     47147.64    2013      2016
9  000004-16 2014-04-25   2016-01-05 2016-03-03 2017-01-12    5644.361  6276.00  34037       0     40313.00    2014      2016
12 000005-15 2014-04-11   2015-01-07 2016-03-02 2015-02-20   11468.442 36060.00      0       0     36060.00    2014      2015
22 000008-14 2013-01-31   2014-01-14 2014-06-10 2014-03-11    9482.826 55215.00      0       0     55215.00    2013      2014
27 000008-15 2014-09-09   2015-01-08 2015-08-19 2015-05-13    3556.742 18500.00  10000       0     28500.00    2014      2015
```

Some sample rows from faktisktdata (containing a total of 22,885 rows):

```
> faktisktdata[1:5,]
          NR skadedatum rapportdatum  slutdatum betaldatum utbetalning  totalut reserv regress skadekostnad skadeår betalår rapportår
2  000002-16 2013-12-03   2016-01-15 2016-11-02 2016-06-20   4126.3044 47147.64      0       0     47147.64    2013    2016      2016
3  000002-16 2013-12-03   2016-01-15 2016-11-02 2016-06-27  40195.0597 47147.64      0       0     47147.64    2013    2016      2016
4  000002-16 2013-12-03   2016-01-15 2016-11-02 2016-11-03   2700.0594 47147.64      0       0     47147.64    2013    2016      2016
12 000005-15 2014-04-11   2015-01-07 2016-03-02 2015-02-20  11468.4415 36060.00      0       0     36060.00    2014    2015      2015
13 000005-15 2014-04-11   2015-01-07 2016-03-02 2015-03-09    705.5974 36060.00      0       0     36060.00    2014    2015      2015
```

The goal is to sample 2,000 observations with replacement from the column called `NR` in `Ndata`. For each element sampled from `Ndata`, I want to extract all rows with the same NR from `faktisktdata`. So if the same value is extracted twice from `Ndata`, I want all rows from `faktisktdata` corresponding to that value to appear twice in my resulting data structure.

Can anyone help me or give any pointers? I would be very grateful.

Comment: How many columns are there in `Ndata`?

Comment: You can store the results in a list and later rbind them using do.call(rbind, your_list). This is much much faster

Comment: @Linus is correct, additionally I recommend  the list items to be matrix and not data frame since `rbind` will be much much faster. If you provide example of the data and a truncated working function I trust you will get answers faster.

Comment: @MKR There are 12 columns in Ndata.

Comment: @Linus Thanks for the tip, I will take a shot at that. I believe I actually tried this earlier, but failed (my R programming skills aren't what they should be).

Comment: @missuse Thanks for the pointers, I added some example data. What do you mean by a truncated working function?

Comment: [This](http://r-statistics.co/Strategies-To-Improve-And-Speedup-R-Code.html) might help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would suggest using `lapply` and `data.table`'s `rbindlist`. The code could look something like this:

```
sample.faktisktdata2 <- function(n) {
  require(data.table)
  Ntriangeldata <- Ndata[sample(nrow(Ndata), n, replace=TRUE),]
  faktiskt.data <- data.frame()

  dtList <- lapply(1:n, function(x) {
      faktisktdata[faktisktdata$NR %in% Ntriangeldata$NR[x],]
    }
  )
  faktiskt.data <- rbindlist(dtList, use.names = T, fill = T)
  faktiskt.data
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for this answer. Execution time of the function was almost halfed, and it now runs in just under 3 seconds. I bet there's still work to be done, but I believe this was the biggest culprit.